# What is the meaning of "Text page 114 contains only floats"?

Tags: floats

I compile using Overleaf and only found this warning. 
When i check, no information is given and direct to a page which I can't find error.

`Text page 114 contains only floats.`

[image]

I am not sure how to produce a MWE instead of whole thesis:

```
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1.7]{example-image}
    \caption{9testing 1234}
    \label{testing}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Mean that a page contain figure and/or table environments but not plain text.  The purpose of floats is to help you to distribute nicely images and tables  *within* the text, so a page only with floats may be not the distribution that you want. It is simply a  warning.

Comment: @Fran. Thanks. it means there is not issue of having only picture in one page? Just simple warming.

Comment: @Fran there are no "simple" warnings. LaTeX only issues a warning when something is wrong.

Comment: hard to tell without seeing any code but I would guess that you have specified that the float may not be put on a float page (which only has floats) , but there is not room to fit any text on the same page as the float so you have an anomalous text page with no text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I had editted my question. However, I am not sure my MWE is correct or not. Basically the warming is because the page is only cover a picture without and text. But is strange it give warning

Comment: @aa not strange at all. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't generate the warning from the posted code even if I add `\documentclass{article}` and load `graphicx` however the markup shown will make the warning not unlikely.

You are specifying

```
 [h!]
```

which is not usually a good choice (LaTeX will usually warn you that it is changing it to `ht`)  however the `h` in particular means **not `p`**  so you are specifying that this float may not be placed on a page that only contains floats.

On a text page, normally latex does not allow the float to be too big so that there is some room to get some actual text on the page; however `!` means "ignore the constraints and place it if it will fit".

So the end result is that it is not at all surprising that you end up with a page that is notionally a text page that has just floats and not enough room for a line of text. That is what the warning is telling you has happened.

`!` should only be used, in the very final editing phase, if you really need to assert control and force some placement. It doesn't make sense to routinely ignore the user specifiable constraints. Similarly note that the optional argument is mostly *restricting* the places where the float is allowed (so making it go to the end of the document more likely as more pages are rejected) so if you don't want to prevent the float going at the top of a page, the bottom of a page or on a page with just floats, don't omit `t`, `b` or `p` from the optional argument.

Of course, with no test document provided it is possible that even if you use `[htbp]` that in the particular circumstances  in your document latex can not find a good placement and you still get this warning, but at least it will have a better chance to find an acceptable placement.

Comment: yes, correct. Thanks a lot. I tried `\begin{figure}[htp!]`

Comment: Carlisel, I changed all, but it seemed other problems, not sure if I check correctly. But I could not figure out `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.`

Comment: @aan as I say above you shouldn't use h on its own and shouldn't use `!` except in special circumstances. If your float is say half a page high but `h` would put it three quarters of the way down the page it can not go "here" so if you use `[h]` it can not go anywhere. old latex then forced it to the end of the document, but latex2e gives that warning and changes it to ht to allow it to go at the top of a later page. but better to use `[htbp]` unless you _intend_ to stop the float going at the top of a page.